# Overflow error VBA same code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pretty simple question.  I wrote this code to look for a preexisting date so that I can replace it. This code has worked perfectly, but I created a copy of the file to run the same code with a separate data set and now the code gets hung up on the fourth line giving me an overflow error. Any idea as to what the root of the problem is?

```
Dim i As Integer, ValueToFind As Integer, LRow As Integer
intValueToFind = Sheet8.Range("K6")
Sheet3.Activate
LRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LRow
If Cells(i, 9).Value = intValueToFind Then
MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
```

Comment: 1. Change all **Integer** to **Long**, 2. Forget you ever heard the word integer.

Comment: @jeeped awesome thank you, that worked perfectly. Just so I can understand, do you have an idea why it would work for one file and not another?

Comment: Because one worksheet has more rows than the maximum for a signed short integer (32,767) but neither had more rows than the maximum of a signed long integer (2,147,483,647). [google-fu](https://www.google.ca/search?q=max+short+signed+integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` is returning a value that's larger than an `Integer` can fit.

`Integer` is a 16-bit signed integer data type, which means its maximum positive value is 32,767, `2^15-1`.

A worksheet can have many, many, many times more rows than that.

Use a `Long` instead, a 32-bit signed integer data type, with a maximum positive value of 2,147,483,647, `2^31-1`.

Don't worry about allocating 32 bits for every integer - on modern computers things are optimized for `Int32` anyway; you hardly ever *need* to use a 16-bit integer type.